# Set up delta load in azure data factory

Tags: t-sql, azure, azure-data-factory

I have an SQL database on prem that I want to get data from. In the database there is a column called last_update that has information about when a row was last updated. The first time I run my pipeline I want it to copy everything from the database on prem to an azure database. The next time I want copy only the rows that have been updated since the last run. I therefore want to copy everything where last_update is higher than the time of the last run. Is there a way of using information about the time of the last run in a pipeline? Is there any other good way of creating what i want?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by developing [custom copy activity](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-use-custom-activities/). You can add your own transformation/processing logic and use the activity in a pipeline.